# How to set invoice date in quickbooks invoice?

Tags: javascript, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using [**quickbooks**](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/invoice#create-an-invoice) and I want to set the invoice date to what ever I want. I am using this code.

If I set it to `TxnDate` field it throws me error. So how can I set the invStartDate?

```
const createInvoiceObj = {
    DocNumber: docNumber,
    Line: [
      {
        Id: "1",
        LineNum: 1,
        Description: `The description`,
        Amount: 1232,
        DetailType: "SalesItemLineDetail",
        SalesItemLineDetail: {
          ItemRef: {
            value: "19",
            name: "Service"
          },
          UnitPrice: 1232,
          Qty: "1"
        }
      }
    ],
    CustomerRef: {
      value: "1"
    },
    CustomerMemo: {
      value: "Thank you for your business and have a great day!"
    },
    TotalAmt: totalAmount,
    TxnDate: moment(order.createdAt).format("YYYY-MM-DD")  // TxnDate: '2020-05-22'
  };
```

[image]

Error I am getting when using TxnDate

```
{
  "Fault": {
    "Error": [
      {
        "Message": "Transaction date is prior to start date for inventory item",
        "Detail": "Transactions with inventory (QOH) products cant be dated earlier than the Inventory Start Date for the product",
        "code": "6270",
        "element": ""
      }
    ],
    "type": "ValidationFault"
  },
  "time": "2020-05-27T05:26:58.217-07:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct field to set the date of the invoice is `TxnDate`.

Example:

```
{
  "Invoice": {
    "TxnDate": "2014-09-19", 
...
```

This is documented well here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/invoice#the-invoice-object

If you get this error message:

```
"Error": [
      {
        "Message": "Transaction date is prior to start date for inventory item",
        "Detail": "Transactions with inventory (QOH) products cant be dated earlier than the Inventory Start Date for the product",
        "code": "6270",
        "element": ""
      }
    ],
```

It means you're sending a date that makes no sense. In a real-world scenario, what you're trying to do is this:

```
You have 0 widgets in inventory 
You try to sell 5 items (you can't, you have zero items in inventory)
You start carrying and stocking widgets in inventory
```

The invoice date needs to be *after* the date you created/started carrying the item/product.

Change the date of the invoice so that the invoice is dated *after* you stated carrying the item/product.

Comment: @DarkKnight updated my answer with specifics about your error message.

Comment: Hi could you pls answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63880970/how-to-automatically-add-quickbooks-redirect-uri)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime('NOW');
```

```html
$i = 1;

while (1) {
    $ccp = new IPPCreditCardPaymentTxn();
    $ccp->TxnData = $dateTime;

    $BankAccountRef = new IPPReferenceType();
    $BankAccountRef->value = "35";
    $BankAccountRef->name = "null";
    $ccp->BankAccountRef = $BankAccountRef;

    $CreditCardAccountRef = new IPPReferenceType();
    $CreditCardAccountRef->value = "41";
    $CreditCardAccountRef->name = "null";
    $ccp->CreditCardAccountRef = $CreditCardAccountRef;
    $ccp->Amount = 10;

    $result = $dataService->add($ccp);

    echo "<br> Result id is: " .$result->Id . "<br><br>";
    $error = $dataService->getLastError();

    if ($error) {
        echo "The Status: " . $error->getHttpStatusCode() . "<br><br>";
        echo "The Helper: " . $error->getOAuthHelperError() . "<br><br>";
        echo "The Response: " . $error->getResponseBody() . "<br><br>";
    } else {
        var_dump($result);
    }
    exit;
}
```

Read: https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/blob/master/src/_Samples/CreditCardPaymentCreate.php

You can change for the data you need to enter.