# How to automatically add Quickbooks redirect uri?

Tags: node.js, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

How can we automatically add the redirect URI in the Quickbooks auth using some API?

[image: k]

Edit:- In my case, my website has functionality of creating sub-domain on the basis of some random keywords. Suppose if my website is facebook.com and someone creates his own company inside it

```
Company name                Website

 1. tata                    tata.facebook.com
 2. tesla                   tesla.facebook.com
```

So I want to add the website url name to the redirect URI as soon as company is created. I don't want to add it like manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we automatically add the redirect URI in the Quickbooks auth using some API?

You can't.

> In my case, my website has functionality of creating sub-domain on the basis of some random keywords.

You won't be able to do this.

A better way to handle this is to have a single domain dedicated to the OAuth handshake for new connections, and always use that domain. You can use the `state` parameter of OAuth to track who is connecting so you know the correct subdomain to bounce them back to after OAuth redirect.

Intuit (and most other cloud providers) do not allow wildcards or dynamic domains because there are some significant security risks to doing so:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.3.5
- http://technotes.iangreenleaf.com/posts/closing-another-nasty-security-hole-in-oauth.html
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180505/why-is-a-wildcard-subdomain-callback-url-in-oauth-considered-unsafe

Comment: Thanks I got you

Comment: Hello sir Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342078/how-to-query-an-account-to-get-only-single-object-in-quickbooks